# Return false is not working in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, return

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numList = {983, 235, 92, 118, 79, 203, 199};
    boolean found;
    System.out.println("Enter the key: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nThe arrays: ");
    printArray(numList);

    if(found = searchKey(numList)) {
        System.out.println(key + " is found in the array");
    } else {
        System.out.println(key + " is not found in the array");
    }
    input.close();
}

public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList) {
    int key = numList[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++);
    if(key == numList[1])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static void printArray(int[] numList) {
    for (int value : numList)
        System.out.println(value + "\t");
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output of this programme only shows *found in the array* even when I type an invalid integer (for example: 4), when the result should be "4 is not found in the array". What am I missing?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++);` <--- Can you tell me what's wrong with this line?  This is why you're encouraged to use `{...}` blocks instead of one line `for` or `if` statements ;)

Comment: even if you remove ; after for loop but the key will be always equal to numList[1] and will return true at the first iteration itself

Comment: `int key = numList[1]; if(key == numList[1])` will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to implement linear search. You have to add another parameter into the search method "key"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numList = {983, 235, 92, 118, 79, 203, 199};

    System.out.println("Enter the key: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nThe arrays: ");
    printArray(numList);

    if(searchKey(numList, key)) 
        System.out.println(key + " is found in the array");
     else 
        System.out.println(key + " is not found in the array");

    input.close();
}

public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList, int key) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
        if(key == numList[i])
            return true; // If anywhere key is found, it will return true
    }
    return false;  // After traversing whole list if key is not found, then it will return false
}

public static void printArray(int[] numList) {
    for (int value : numList)
        System.out.print(value + "\t");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Run this programme and the return true is not working.

Comment: @fatind see [this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/VdxwHGotQN). Its working

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++);
```

I think the ; at the end of the line is suspicious. You might want to remove it.

Comment: I did as told and a wavy red line is formed in my searchKey(int[] numList)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you.I have added a parameter `key` of type `int` to the function, which will be the number user will be entering. I have enclosed the search inside the `for loop` and changed the `if` expression as `key == numList[i]`. Here am comparing the key with each elements in the array list.

And remember am only returning `true` if I find a matching element in the array list. If the for loop exit without finding a matching element in the array list it will return `false`.

```
public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++){
        if(key == numList[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As I have added a new parameter to the searchKey() method the call made to the method will have to be modified as well. So I will pass the array list and also  the key entered by the user as follows.

```
if(found = searchKey(numList, key)) {
    System.out.println(key + " is found in the array");
} else {
    System.out.println(key + " is not found in the array");
}
```

Comment: Did this. Now only the return false works. Whenever I type the correct integer, I still get a "(insert valid integer) is not found in the array"

Answer (score 0):

`numList[1]` is not the key,

The function should be :

```
public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList, int key) {
    boolean status = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++){
        if(key == numList[i])
            status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

and call it :

```
if(searchKey(numList, key)) {
    System.out.println(key + " is found in the array");
} else {
    System.out.println(key + " is not found in the array");
}
```

Comment: I did as told and a new error occured; a wavy red line is formed in my searchKey(int[] numList, int key)

Comment: @fatind : I forgot the `;` in the end of status, try it again

Comment: Did it. Now only the return false works. Whenever I type the correct integer, I still get a "(insert valid integer) is not found in the array"

Answer (score 0):

Return false always works in java if we write it in correct way :)

there were few of the modification which was needed to be done in order to achieve required functionality.

1. The key wasn't passed to searchKey() to perform actual search
2. for loops with ; at end is of no use to achieve required functionality, therefore have been removed.
3. array index starts with 0th position.

Have put down working program with above tweaks.

This can be optimize further, if you wish to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numList = {983, 235, 92, 118, 79, 203, 199};
        boolean found;
       System.out.println("Enter the key: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nThe arrays: ");
    printArray(numList);

    if(searchKey(numList, key)) {
        System.out.println(key + " is found in the array");
    } else {
        System.out.println(key + " is not found in the array");
    }
    input.close();
}

public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
        if (key == numList[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void printArray(int[] numList) {
    for (int value : numList)
        System.out.println(value + "\t");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function searchKey(int[] numList)  is incorrectly written. You need to pass key along with your array. You are not passing any key and taking array's first element as a key and comparing your first element of array with key (which is nothing but the array's first element).

Your code:

```
public static boolean searchKey(int[] numList) {
int key = numList[1];
for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++);
if(key == numList[1])
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

It should be:

```
public static boolean searchKey(int key, int[] numList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
        if(key == numList[i])
            return true ;
    }
    return false ;
}
```